# Tate–Shafarevich group- Solutions in $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{Q}_p$ but not in $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-cohomology

Let $K$ be a field. By [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%E2%80%93Shafarevich_group), “the group measures the extent to which the Hasse principle fails to hold for rational equations with coefficients in the field $K$”. How one can intuitively see this application of the Tate–Shafarevich group?

Moreover, are there any more such important applications to the Tate–Shafarevich group?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, the Tate-Shafarevich group is a cohomology group in the “purest” sense – it measures how much the situation differs from the ideal world (Galois cohomology classes always arise from rational points) and is basically inaccessible otherwise.